# Is there function for displaying text in R window?

Tags: r

Is there function for displaying text in R window ? and how to display text written with HTML formating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gplots/topics/textplot

As for HTML, I'm not sure how that makes sense--is your R window a web browser?

Comment: sure I have very slow computer, so I want to use R instead of ff

Comment: @MysteryGuy: Fixed again.  Link rot for R documentation is out of control!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `file.show`?

> Display one or more (plain) text files, in a platform specific way, typically via a ‘pager’ (`help(file.show)`).

Answer (score -1):

It isn't clear what you mean by "R window" but `print` will print text:

```
print("Hello World")
```

or

```
x <- "Hello World"
print(x)
```

gives

```
[1] Hello World
```

[Documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/print.html)